# Problemas na criação de arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Boa noite! Estou tentando criar um arquivo txt de uma lista de clientes, para isto criei um looping a fim de armazenar 2 clientes e espero que o arquivo criado guarde estes dados no txt, todavia ele só está guardando um cliente a cada execução! Podem me explicar o que está acontecendo? Comecei a aprender sobre ponteiros agora, então provavelmente é algo muito simples e, apesar de estar consultando meus materiais ainda não consigo encontrar o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
 struct lista_clientes
{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    int telefone;
    char endereco[100];
};

main()
{
    FILE *arqu_file; /*declaração do ponteiro para criação do arquivo*/
    arqu_file= fopen("Clientes.txt","a+"); /*abertura do arquivo*/
    if (arqu_file == NULL) /*teste do arquivo*/
    {
        printf("Houve um ERRO!");
    }
    int i;
     struct lista_clientes Clientes[2];         
        for (i=0;i<2;i++)       /*laço de repetição a priori para 20 clientes*/
        {
            printf("Nome do cliente: "); scanf(" %s",Clientes[i].nome);
            printf("Idade do cliente: "); scanf("%i",&Clientes[i].idade);
            printf("Telefone do cliente: "); scanf("%i",&Clientes[i].telefone);
            fflush(stdin);          /* necessario para o buffer*/
            printf("Endereco do cliente: "); gets(Clientes[i].endereco);
            fprintf(arqu_file,"%s %i %s %i",Clientes[i].endereco,Clientes[i].idade,Clientes[i].nome,Clientes[i].telefone);
            fclose(arqu_file);
            getc(arqu_file);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja o fato que você fechou o arquivo dentro do for, aí quando ele executa pela 2ª vez não é mais possível escrever.